# possible to reset .gif img src in browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, refresh, gif, reset

I've been trying to figure out how to reset a gif image from inside javascript,
before i'd just add `<?php echo date("Ymdgis");?>` trailing the image which worked for inline script inside a php template.

I'm trying to refresh the image **`http://website/wp-content/themes/file/images/splash1.gif`**
each time the browser refreshes.

```
var splash = new Image();
splash.src = "http://website/wp-content/themes/file/images/splash1.gif";
splash.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('here').src = splash.src;
}
```

This function would append the .gif image into the #here element inside my html.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the query parameter every time the image is loaded in the browser, then the browser will not have that URL in the cache and thus will make a fresh request from the server:

```
var splash = new Image();
splash.src = "http://website/wp-content/themes/file/images/splash1.gif?" + Date.now();
splash.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('here').src = splash.src;
}
```